# Select count() when field is unique

Tags: sql, count, unique, visual-foxpro

I'm using SQL in vfp so some of my commands are different. `iif([condition],[if true],[if false])` is used instead of `case when`.

here's my code:

```
SELECT
    giftsource,
    COUNT(donor) AS total_gifts, /*this is not the one that need fixed*/
    SUM(amt) AS total_amt,
    SUM(iif(unique = 1 AND language != 'F' AND renew = '0' AND type = 'IN',1,0)) as d_Count_E_New_Indiv,
    SUM(iif(unique = 1 AND language = 'F' AND renew = '0' AND type = 'IN',1,0)) as d_Count_F_New_Indiv,
    SUM(iif(unique = 1 AND language != 'F' AND renew != '0' AND type = 'IN',1,0)) as d_Count_E_Re_Indiv,
    SUM(iif(unique = 1 AND language = 'F' AND renew != '0' AND type = 'IN',1,0)) as d_Count_F_Re_Indiv,
    SUM(iif(unique = 1 AND language != 'F' AND renew = '0' AND type != 'IN',1,0)) as d_Count_E_New_Org,
    SUM(iif(unique = 1 AND language = 'F' AND renew = '0' AND type != 'IN',1,0)) as d_Count_F_New_Org,
    SUM(iif(unique = 1 AND language != 'F' AND renew != '0' AND type != 'IN',1,0)) as d_Count_E_Re_Org,
    SUM(iif(unique = 1 AND language = 'F' AND renew != '0' AND type != 'IN',1,0)) as d_Count_F_Re_Org,
FROM (select *,
            cast( /* equivalent to a bunch of if elses*/
                iif(  list_code="WEB","1",
                iif(  list_code="GRO","2",
                iif(  list_code="CHO","3",
                iif(  list_code="TEL","4",
                iif(  list_code="TES","5",
                iif(  list_code="POS" AND amt < 10000,"6",
                iif( (LIKE(list_code,"4%") OR list_code = "4") AND amt < 10000,"7",
                iif( (LIKE(list_code,"4%") OR list_code = "4" OR list_code = "POS") AND amt >= 10000,"8",
                iif(  LIKE(list_code,"9%") OR list_code = "9","9",
                "10"))))))))) as c(1))
            as giftsource
        from cGift) gift
    LEFT JOIN
            (select didnumb, language, type from dp) d
        on cast(gift.donor as i) = cast(d.didnumb as i)
    LEFT JOIN /*this does not do what i want it to*/
            (select min(gidnumb) gid, 1 as unique from cGift group by donor) uGift
        on gift.gidnumb = uGift.gid
GROUP BY giftsource
ORDER BY giftsource
```

What this code should do is find how many donors donated within each gift category. It shouldn't count duplicate donors within the same field (i.e. same list_code/lang/renew/etc.) but it should count a donor twice if it's another field.

Example: donor #3 can only be counted once in d_Count_E_New_Indiv but can also be counted in d_Count_E_New_Org.

gidnumb is the primary key in this table.

With my second join i attached a field (named unique) to the first donor in the table. This doesn't work because it only counts the donor in one field.

Can someone tell me what the right way to do it is? Also i have a lot more SUM(...) that aren't based on unique donors so i'd prefer to not butcher my select too much.

EDIT: i fixed it by using the following `select count(distinct IIF(renew = '0' AND lang != 'F',donor,0)) FROM dpgift`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a single query that groups on all the relevant fields (looks like giftsource, language, renew and type) to get one record for each combination with the count you need:

```
SELECT giftsource, language, renew, type, COUNT(*) ;
  FROM <whatever tables and joins you need> ;
  GROUP BY giftsource, language, renew, type
```

Then, you can either join this to whatever else you need or use some Xbase code to pull it into a single row. You could also look at doing a crosstab (with either VFPXTab or one of the 3rd party tools) to pivot the data.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get away with  COUNT(distinct donor) AS total_gifts, i don't have visual fox pro and did some googling and it is mentioned.

Comment: yeah i can do `select count(distinct donor)`. How would i put this into my code though? I'm using `sum(iif(expression,1,0))` because i need a filter.

Comment: oh, it's not total_gifts that needs fixed. It's all the sums() acting as counts.